# python 2.6.6 "phantom" whitespaces

Tags: python

Basically, I'm opening some files and removing all whitespaces from every line in that file.
code snippet:

```
for filepath in filelist:
        if filepath.endswith(".shader"):
            shaderfile = open(filepath,"r").readlines()
            for line in shaderfile:
                line = Left(line, line.find("\n"))+"\n"
                line = line.replace(" ","")
                if line.find("common/")>-1:
                    print(line.replace("\n","\\n"))
```

As per request, I removed the less important code.

There are two weird things going on:

1) Some lines end with "\n\n"

2) I'm getting this output:

```
textures/common/lightgrid\n
textures/common/mirror1
 \n
textures/common/mirror2
 \n
maptextures/common/invisible.tga
 \n
textures/common/watercaulk
 \n
textures/common/clipnokick
 \n
textures/common/invisible\n
```

3) When I pasted the output here, it looked like:

```
textures/common/lightgrid\n
textures/common/mirror1\n
textures/common/mirror2\n
maptextures/common/invisible.tga\n
textures/common/watercaulk\n
textures/common/clipnokick\n
textures/common/invisible\n
```

I seriously have no idea what's going on. Is it a bug with print()?
Sorry for the bad formatting, but it's not my fault, it's stackoverflow's.

Comment: What is `Left()`? Also: use `if " " in line` instead of `line.find(" ")>-1`.

Comment: oh, sorry, forgot about that. Left(string,count) returns the first [count] characters of [string]. And that should be unnecessary, coz I'm replacing any " " with "" anyway.

Comment: I'm gonna turn mad with this site's formatting. It's repeatedly changing >:I

Comment: That `Left(string,count)` function could be replaced with `string[:count]` unless negative values of `count` are intended to be handled differently by it.

Comment: They are, but thanks for the hint anyways.

Comment: @Rawing - I have reformatted it for you. Please fix it if necessary - just put four (4) spaces before each line to show it like a code with grey background.

Answer (score 1):

```
from StringIO import StringIO

a = StringIO("""textures/common/lightgrid
textures/common/mirror1

textures/common/mirror2

maptextures/common/invisible.tga

textures/common/watercaulk

textures/common/clipnokick

textures/common/invisible""")


def clean_lines(fileobj):
    for line in fileobj:
        if line:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                yield "%s\n" % line


print [line for line in clean_lines(a)]
```

I used stringIO to emulate a file just replace a with whatever your fileobj is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want output like

```
textures/common/lightgrid\ntextures/common/mirror1\n...
```

and instead you're getting

```
textures/common/lightgrid\n
textures/common/mirror1\n
...
```

This is because `print` *statement* adds an implicit newline.

You can use normal file output:

```
from sys import stdout
# ...
stdout.write("foo") # adds no implicit newline
```

You can use *function* `print()` ported back from Python 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
#
print("foo", end="") # use empty string instead of default newline
```

Also, if you need to remove whitespace from *inside* of your strings, you can make it far simpler and probably more efficient.

```
import re # regular expressions
whitespace_rx = re.compile(r"\s+") # matches any number of whitespace
# ...
splinters = whitespace_rx.split(raw_line) # "a b\nc" -> ['a','b','c']
compacted_line = "".join(splinters) # ['a','b','c'] -> 'abc'
```

Of course you can just replace `splinters` with the `.split()` call.

Comment: `re` is only for a case of removing whitespace from _inside_ of the lines. Original poster's code seems to to do that, too, see that `line.replace(' ', '')` and code above it. Of course, if only leading and ending whitespace needs to be removed, `.strip()` is enough.

Comment: .strip() works like a charm, kills all the "\n" as well, though. Now, if only I knew how to mark this as solved >.< But nobody seems to know what the bug in my code is...

Comment: @Rawing: if you managed to significantly simplify your code, maybe you could post the updated version. In simpler code the bug might be more obvious.